# As a new user I want a user-interface key to quickly understand what all of the different colors and symbols mean

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, new-users, site-faq

Please add a graphical key to the FAQs of all the sites that explains the meaning of colors and symbols found on the site, including the question lists / search results and the question and answer pages.  The following question contains a lot of this information, but it was **hard to find and should be much more visible** (and possibly more comprehensive)!  If I am missing something, please let me know.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean

Comment: This is a reasonable request and I believe it should be added to the FAQ, we've got all that nice jquery to hide stuff if it gets too long.  My suggestion is to take that question and incorporate into FAQ.

Answer (score 7):

If you're confused about symbols, pretty much *every* symbol will have a hover tooltip that explains what it does or why it's there. If you want a quick reference, here:

[image: All symbols explained.]

As for the colors, I don't see how they're that difficult to figure out that they warrant space in the FAQ.

The FAQ is meant to hold the most *frequently* asked questions, and I believe the questions that are in there summarize how to use the site in the best way possible. Adding in every detail to the FAQ eliminates the use of the FAQ. The more people see there is to read, the less they want to read it, and we certainly *want* people to read it.

Comment: I can't read that.  Its perfect for meta.

Comment: I'm not convinced. While the hover over is great and I think those symbols you are referring to are intuitive to me, the color coding behind the answer boxes is not.  I could not find easily find what they mean and what the possible combinations were;  I had to dig for it;  I found it in the answer to the question I linked to in my question. That type of basic usability information should be easy to find. If the FAQ section is not the appropriate place for it, then how can we make it easier for new users to find?